# Find all orders in WooCommerce according to a custom meta field, and update their order status

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

**The Long Story:**
So I inherited a project from a previous developer who didn't have time to do this project in a better way. The project is a tour company. And they use WooCommerce for people to schedule their tours. You get online and buy a ticket, and put in the date you want to go into a custom field. The client then bought WooCommerce's Follow-Up Emails. He wants to send out an email to his customer after they've finished the ride, and ask them for reviews or whatnot. Followup email can't detect the custom date field, so instead, i set it to go off on a custom order status we made, "Completed Tour". So now when he finishes a day of touring, he goes back into the system and sets the people who rode with him to "Completed Tour." Then that triggers the email system to fire off.

People who buy this tour by it throughout the year, however, so he might have to go back six to nine months to find the person that rode today. That just won't work.

**Short story:**
So I'd like to pull a list of all the orders whose custom date field was before today, and change their status to the custom status: "Completed Tour".

Theoretically, this SQL code would do the trick:

```
"SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'Ride Date' AND meta_value <= $today"

"UPDATE wp_posts SET post_status = 'wc-completed-tour' WHERE post_id = $post_id AND post_status = 'wc-completed'"
```

But that just feels awfully dangerous. Is there a better way of accomplishing this without having to rewrite the whole system?

Comment: you can add the select (as part of the WHERE) in to the update, you don't need 2 queries - as for  dangerous - i don't see why

Comment: Thanks @Dagon, I might do that, except I haven't decided yet whether I want to give my client the option to approve or disapprove each one first before firing it off.

Comment: @Dagon, as for the "dangerous" part, I feel it's always just a bit dangerous when you have a complex system managing a database and then you skip past it and manually edit that db. I do know that wordpress uses data serialization which can screw with stuff if you edit it, but I don't know that that applies to this particular situation. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: well the alternative is to fine a woocommerce expert to modify it for you.